# Help with a MySQL SELECT WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, mysql

A column in my table contains email addresses.

I have a text string that contains the a few usernames of email addresses separated by commas. I can make text sting into an array if necessary to get my SELECT WHERE clause to work correctly.

Text string search argument is 'bob,sally,steve'

I want to produce a WHERE clause that only returns rows where the username portion of the email address in the table matches one of the usernames in my text string search argument.

Thus a row with frank@email.com would not be returned but sally@zmail.com would be.

Does anyone have a WHERE clause sample that produces this result?

Thanks.

Comment: What about franksally@email.com?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Ooooo good one! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
WHERE email like '%bob%' or email like '%sally%' or email like '%steve%'
```

Note that this will also match `adjklqwefh@bob.com`. If you only want to match the starting characters, simply omit the leading `%`:

```
WHERE email like 'bob%' or email like 'sally%' or email like 'steve%'
```

If you want to be more restrictive, you could try:

```
WHERE email like 'bob@%.com' or email like 'sally@%.com' or email like 'steve@%.com'
```

Also, read up on the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator, and regular expressions (you shoudln't need it here, but you'll probably need it eventually).

Comment: I only wanted it for addresses beginning with the username so I omitted the beginning % for my test and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you but I think it will be very slow

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(email, 1, (LOCATE('@', email) - 1)) in ('steve', 'smith', .... )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement will select any rows in the 'email' column where the address starts with "bob@".
You would would substitute "bob" with the username you are trying to match.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email REGEXP "^bob@"
```

Comment: No, didn't work...REGEXP "^bob@" OR REGEXP "^sally@" OR REGEXP "^steve@" -- no rows returned

Comment: If you are adding multiple conditions, the query would be like this: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email REGEXP "^bob@" OR email REGEXP "^sally@" OR email REGEXP "^steve@"

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed/overlooked the column name part (dah)

Comment: Tried it that way and it still didn't work..I have a solution that works -- so I am moving on..thanks guys.